# Prevent Navigation Bar from collapsing and being sticky when on scroll SwiftUI / UIKit

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar, navigationview

[image]I would like the NavigationBar (from a SwiftUI NavigationView) to **just stay large and scroll out whenever I scroll in a Pages ScrollView**. Right now it is always collapsing and showing even on scroll in ".inline"-display mode. So when I try to completely hide it I also hide the large title I'd like to keep.
Is there a way to just let it stay large and just scroll out?
Any solution in SwiftUI or UIKit is appreciated as I can introspect from UIKit.

I especially don't want the NavigationBar to be hidden and rebuild by VStack or HStack as this causes loosing all Navigation Gestures like swiping back to the previous Navigation View and so...

Here is a basic codesnipped to recreate

```
struct TestTestView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView() {
            Color.green
                .frame(height: 1000)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Test")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Give us some code so we can rebuild the problem ourselves

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example. I hope this makes it more reproducable :)